# Yii2 - Data Not Coming To vova07 / yii2-imperavi-widget (textarea)

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-widget

I've just installed **vova07 / yii2-imperavi-widget** through `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget "*".`
And, it's working fine for inserting any content to database table. But, I'm in awkward situation when fetching data into this this widget

I want to fetch the data. So, I created one `'value' => $postDetails['desc']`. **Data Not Coming to it**.

```
<?= $form->field($modelEditPost, 'desc')->widget(Widget::className(), [
  'settings' => [
            'value' => $postDetails['desc'],
            'lang' => 'ru','minHeight' => 200,'plugins' => ['clips','fullscreen']]
]);?>
```

But, when i'm including

```
<?= $form->field($modelEditPost, 'desc')->textarea(['rows' => 6,'value'=>$postDetails['desc']]) ?>
```

(which was previously present to fetch data) along with widget, **Data coming to widget** (But, not in textarea))

```
<?= $form->field($modelEditPost, 'desc')->textarea(['rows' => 6,'value'=>$postDetails['desc']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($modelEditPost, 'desc')->widget(Widget::className(), [
  'settings' => [
            'value' => $postDetails['desc'],
            'lang' => 'ru','minHeight' => 200,'plugins' => ['clips','fullscreen']]
]);?>
```

Actually, I want data to be fetched into widget.

Please help me to rectify this issue.

Comment: Useful: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html

Comment: @InsaneSkull : Thanks for giving link. But, I don't have problem in inserting / fetching. Insertion is OK. Only fetching problem come when i dont't declare activeFrom textarea to it (which is not necessary at all)

Comment: i am not getting your question, elaborate more.

Comment: Before I was using default active form textrea to display content. Now, requirement came to use any texteditor. So, i installed it. 
**Problem is :**  value not coming to widget when i want to edit my content. It is only coming in widget when i'm using default active form textrea + that widget (as i showed in question). So, why value coming only when i am including textarea along with widget @InsaneSkull

Comment: pass id of textbox to widget.

Comment: Now, value coming to textarea and not in widget. @InsaneSkull

Comment: show `$postDetails` array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97626/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-nana-partykar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$modelEditPost->desc = $postDetails['desc']`:

```
$modelEditPost->desc = $postDetails['desc'];
  <?= $form->field($modelEditPost, 'desc')->widget(Widget::className(), [
'settings' => ['lang' => 'ru','minHeight' => 200,'plugins' => ['clips','fullscreen']]
]);?>
```